# Convert gmdate in laravel's Carbon PHP API Extention for Datetime

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen

I have installed Carbon in my laravel application. But didnt found any function which will give similar result as gmdate in php.

I have tried following but it didnt help me out:

```
echo gmdate("YmdH", (time() + 19800)).'<br/>';
echo Carbon::createFromTimeStampUTC('YmdH', (time() + 19800));
```

I want to implement similar functionality as gmdate provides in laravel using Carbon

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to pass a timezone as the third parameter of `createFromFormat()`

```
createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )
```

So you could do something like this:

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/London');
$date->setTimezone('UTC');
```